# When to return IHttpActionResult vs Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In examples of using the ASP.NET Web API I see two different methods used to return data to the calling jQuery function. The first method returns an object of type `Client` but I am not sure what the second method is returning.

**Method #1** (returns `Client` object)

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetAllClients()
{
     using (var context = new PQRSModel.PQRSEntities())
     {
       context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 
       var query = context.Clients.OrderBy(c = c.OrgName);
       var customers = query.ToList();
       return customers;
     }
}
```

**Method #2** (What benefit does `IHttpActionResult` provide?)

```
public IHttpActionResult GetClient(int clientId)
{
     using (var context = new PQRSModel.PQRSEntities())
     {
       context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
       var client = context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c = c.ID == clientId);
       if (client == null)
       {
         return NotFound();
       }
       return Ok(client);
     }
}
```

If the second method finds a single object is there any reason it could not also return a `Client` object type?

Answer (score 21):

Returning `IHttpActionResult` provides a nice **separation of concerns**.

Your controller can focus on responding to the request in the most sensible manner (status codes, error messages, etc.). Another (service) layer can focus on actually retrieving and transforming the business data.

The side-effect is, your controller methods become more *unit testable*. Consider the following simple example:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    //or better yet, dependency-inject this
    SomeService _service = new SomeService();

    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
         if (id < 0)
             return BadRequest("Some error message");

         var data = _service.GetData(id);

         if (data == null)
            return NotFound();

         return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

Not only is this method's logic understandable *just by reading it*, but you could now test the logic more easily and naturally, something like (using NUnit syntax):

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyControllerTests
{    
    [Test]
    public void Get_WithIdLessThan0_ReturnsBadRequest()
    {
        var controller = new MyController();
        int id = -1;

        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Get(id);

        Assert.IsInstanceOf<BadRequestErrorMessageResult>(actionResult);
    }
}
```

Similarly, you could mock the Service layer and test what happens when you give known `id` parameters to the controller, etc.

Here is a good article on [Unit Testing Controllers in Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api)

Comment: This is more an argument for creating a service layer than it is for returning an `IHttpActionResult`. Once you've separated concerns properly, testing that the action throws a particular exception type is about as simple as testing that it returns a given action result type.

Comment: Which is exactly why I used that test case as my *example* - it was simple to code up in an answer, but illustrates the idea. Please do add your own answer if you believe mine to be insufficient.

Answer (score 10):

The second method allows you to return just status codes (like the 404 in the example), streaming file content and other types of non-object content.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can objects still be returned using the 'IHttpActionResult' or should the first method be used when you want to return a single object or collection of objects? Reason I ask is the example (Microsoft Article - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) I was going through used the method returning `IHttpActionResult` to return an object. I was trying to adapt the code to return an Entity framework object.

Comment: There are a few advantages of returning the objects directly from the method. The method signature will define it better and the method will be easier to test. Status codes such as 404 when the object is not found or 400 for bad input data can be returned by throwing exceptions of type `HttpResponseException` instead of being returned by the `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: But exceptions are costly, and your method signatures don't really have anything to do with your API (rather the API explorer gathers information from them when no other information is present).

One of the (I think unavoidable) shortcomings in Web API is the marriage of routing concepts, HTTP layer, and OOP in a way that doesn't always make sense.

There is, however, a way around this while still using IHttpActionResult. It's the `ResponseTypeAttribute`.

Comment: Exceptions are only costly compared to some things. When you consider all the reflection and I/O required to wire a given request into the controller code, and then to translate the result into a response, the added overhead of throwing and catching an exception is pretty reasonable.

Comment: I still wouldn't consider most status codes to be "exceptions" from a semantic point of view.  e.g. A `404` should be expected.  I agree an object provides a more specific api however.  Personally I feel a generic would help describe the api best `IHttpActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>`.

Answer (score 1):

The argument for using `IHttpActionResult` is that it allows you to return different status codes from the Action.

Let's consider the example below:

```
public Client GetClient(int id)
{
   if (id <= 0)
   {
      throw new BadRequestException("Invalid Id"); // 400
   }

   var client = _myDbService.GetClient(id);
   if (client == null)
   {
      throw new NotFoundException("Client not found"); // 404
   }
   
   return Ok(client); // 200
}
```

The only way we can return 400 and 404 is by throwing exception.

*Note that the code above does not include the exception handling logic. You need to write the logic to return the desired status code with any additional error message (if any) in your exception handler.*

If we change the return type to `IHttpActionResult` then we can handle the failure scenarios without throwing any exceptions:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Client found", Type = typeof(Client))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid id")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Client not found")]
public IHttpActionResult GetClient(int id)
{
   if (id <= 0)
   {
      return BadRequest("Invalid id");
   }

   var client = _myDbService.GetClient(id);
   if (client == null)
   {
      return NotFound();   
   }
   
   return Ok(client);
}
```

Note that, you can use `SwaggerResponse` attribute to specify the return type for each status code.

---

I don't know which method is better but it seems like [Microsoft prefers the second option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results):

> A disadvantage of this approach [first option] is that you cannot directly return an
> error code, such as 404. However, you can throw an
> HttpResponseException for error codes.